# Switching applications on a single desktop on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> only allows us to switch between all the applications.

Once I have moved the less used applications on a different desktop on my Mac I don't want to see them in the application switcher as it makes everything more confusing.

Is there a way to do that?

I have an options of pressing the <kbd>F3</kbd> key to open mission control and then select the app on that desktop using the mouse which is slower.

Can I select an app from the mission control using the keyboard only?

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the functionality you describe when I ended up here, and even though Lri mentioned that [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/) couldn't get the job done I tried it out. It turns out it was possible.
I can't say the configuration to make it happen was obvious, so I can't blame Lri for saying it wasn't possible.

Anyhow, bellow are the settings that worked for me. Hope this helps!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb79v.png)

- Actions tab:

  - Cycle Apps > Windows
  - Sort by: App Activity > Window Activity
  - Orientation: "->"
  - List windows from all spaces: Unchecked
  - List tabs: Checked
  - Mode: Automatic
  - List apps without windows: Unchecked

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any command-tab alternative that could only show applications that have windows on the current desktop. [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) can't.

If you want to cycle through the windows on the current desktop in order, you can use use the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> / <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. It doesn't show any kind of menu though, and sometimes it selects windows from hidden applications. You can change the shortcut from the keyboard preference pane.

I never use spaces, command-tab, or mission control. It's faster to [switch applications with keyboard shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/20116#20116), and OS X's implementation of virtual desktops isn't really usable in my opinion.

Related questions:

- [Restricting Command+tab options to only apps that are in the current space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/restricting-commandtab-options-to-only-apps-that-are-in-the-current-space)
- [Switch between groups of windows](https://superuser.com/questions/472120/switch-between-groups-of-windows-osx?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sorta achieve this in Big Sur with the help of [Contexts](https://contexts.co/). My implementation allows the following functionality:

1. Cycle through non minimized Windows only in Visible (current) Space, with `command+tab`,
2. Cycle through all Windows of the same App regardless of their Space and if minimized, with `command+tilde`,
3. Search all open Windows, minimized or not, in all Spaces, with `control+space`.

Here are some screenshots with the settings I set:

[Cycle through non minimized Windows only in Visible (current) Space, `command+tab`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbHYy.png)

[Cycle through all Windows of the same App regardless of their Space and if minimized, `command+tilde`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTGhj.png)

[Search all open Windows, minimized or not, in all Spaces, `control+space`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A982.png)

Give it a try, I hope it'll help.

Edit: And [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCFBa.png) how I disabled the built-in Sidebar.

Edit 2: Changed wording in functionality 1 and 2 for a more accurate description.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran across an app that does this well: [Command-Tab Plus](http://commandtab.noteifyapp.com/).

Comment: Please do not post only a link to the software's download page. Please see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/10259) then edit your answer to include at least the minimum required information (the items in **bold**). Answers without this information may be subject to deletion.